# Converting pseudocode to an odd/evenness sort

Tags: python

So I found the following pseudocode on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort#Algorithm):

```
function oddEvenSort(list) {
  sorted = false;
  while(!sorted)
  {
    sorted = true;
    for(i = 1; i < list.length-1; i += 2)
    {
      if(list[i] > list[i+1])
      {
        Swap list[i] and list[i+1]
        sorted = false;
       }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < list.length-1; i += 2)
    {
      if(list[i] > list[i+1])
      {
        Swap list[i] and list[i+1]
        sorted = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to write it in Python:

```
def oddEvenSort(List):
     sorted = False
     while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for (i == 1 and i < List.length-1 and i == i+2): #getting a syntax error here
            if (List[i] > List[i+1]):
                List[i], List[i+1] = List[i+1], List[i]
                sorted = False

        for (i == 0 and i < List.length-1 and i == i+2):
            if (List[i] > List[i+1]):
                List[i], List[i+1] = List[i+1], List[i]
                sorted = False

def main():
    x = input("Please enter a list of numbers: ")
    y = oddEvenSort(x)
    print(y)

main()
```

However, I get several errors with this code. How can I remove them?

Comment: And what errors are you seeing? What's the question here?

Comment: syntax error in line 5

Comment: Please edit you question to include your error message.

Comment: this is just bubblesort ... but partitioning the list for some reason that makes no sense ....

Comment: Don't try to edit your question to remove all the content. That makes the answers you received useless.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: It actually does make _some_ sense—unlike bubble sort, you can trivially implement this on two processors with compare-exchange with no locks. There's a 1972 paper on it, which is pretty early research on lock-free programming. I found it in [the Wikipedia article the OP forgot to link to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code above. I will address them all:

- Writing for loops and using iteration
- Returning from a function
- Best practice not to shadow built-ins
- Parsing input

**Writing for loops and iteration:**

> for(i = 1; i < list.length-1; i += 2)

is written as (*in Python*):

```
for i in range(1, (len(list) - 1), 2)
```

See: [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

**Returning from a function:**

Your function `oddEvenSort()` also does not return anything.

So `y = oddEvenSort(...)` will return `None`. You need a `return list` at the end of the function.

**NOT Shadowing built-ins:**

DO NOT shadow built-in types and functions such as `list()` with variables named `list`. Use `xs` or something more appropriately named.

**Parsing input:**

Thanks to Joran Beasley; Yes your `input` is not in the correct form (*yet*). Try converting this to a list of integers by doing something like:

```
s =  input("Enter some numbers (comma separated):")
xs = [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]  # clean input
ys = list(map(int, xs))  # map input list into actual integers
```

Comment: Thanks for that fix! By the way, when I execute the code and enter a list of numbers, the output is `None`. Why is this?

Comment: entered: `3,2,5,6,8` output: `None`

Comment: @PaneerPushpam because you don't return a value from your `oddEvenSort` function and functions in Python that don't explicitly return values have a return value of `None`

Comment: `input` is also just giving you back a string `"3,2,5,6,8"` not a list ... you need to convert that to a list

Comment: Like this? `x = (input("Please enter a list of numbers: "))
    p =[]
    for i in x:
        p.append(i)
    y = oddEvenSort(p)
    print(y)

Comment: `map` doesn't create a list on Python 3, must be `list(map())`

Comment: @Antti Haapala Thanks corrected :) I don't actively work with Python 3 (*still!*) :)