# Write a program that separates odd and even numbers in a list

Tags: python

I wrote a program that separates odd and even numbers in a list. Sometimes my program works and sometimes it does not. For example, if I enter a list of numbers: `4,6,99,78`, the output is `['4', '6', '78', '99']`. That is fine, but when I enter `2,3,4,5`, the output is `['2', '3', '4', '5']`. This is unbearable, please help me fix this!

My program:

```
def oddEvenSort(List):
 Sorted = False
 while not Sorted:
    Sorted = True
    for i in range(1, len(List)-1,2):
        if (List[i] > List[i+1]):
            List[i], List[i+1] = List[i+1], List[i]
            Sorted = False

    for i in range(0, len(List)-1,2):
        if (List[i] > List[i+1]):
            List[i], List[i+1] = List[i+1], List[i]
            Sorted = False
  return List
def main():
  xs = (input("Enter some numbers (comma separated):").split(","))
  p = []
  for i in xs:
    p.append(i)
  y = oddEvenSort(p)
  print(y)

main()
```

Comment: The first thing I'd recommend is changing your `sorted` variable to some other name so that you don't mask the built-in function `sorted()`.

Comment: I'm not seeing where this looks at whether a number is odd or even. It just sorts the `list` slightly. Would you be okay with a completely different algorithm?

Comment: When this works, it's only by accident. As TigerhawkT3 points out, it's not even _attempting_ to sort by odd/evenness. It _is_ attempting to sort by value, but (a) that isn't even in the right direction of solving your problem, and (b) you did it wrong anyway (this appears to be an attempt at an O(N^2) bubble sort?). If you can't explain how this is _supposed_ to work, nobody can help you fix it. People can give you an entirely new program, but what good will that do you?

Comment: (Not to mention that sorting numbers by their string representation is kind of silly, unless you want `'12' < '2'`.)

Comment: this is a horrible sorting function .... where did you say you found the pseudo-code?

Comment: and here is the exact same question that you shredded for some dumb reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064191/python-3-adding-two-numbers-and-converting-them-to-a-string

Comment: At least this one explains what you're trying to do, while the first one didn't. But you should have edited that information into the original question, not posted an entirely new question and then tried to edit out the text of the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maps each element to an `int` just in case the `List` is a `list` of strings, then sorts that iterable's elements based on whether they're even. `sorted()` provides a stable sort (even numbers will be in their original order relative to each other, odd numbers will be in their original order relative to each other).

```
def oddEvenSort(List):
    return sorted(map(int, List), key=lambda num: num%2)
```

Improvements thanks to @Shashank's comment.

Comment: Well I think the primary issue is that he is not mapping his list elements to ints first. Also I would use `return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x % 2)`. Potentially with `reverse=True` optional argument to get odds first, then evens.

Comment: Very true on both counts. I'll fix it.

Comment: You actually don't really need to map list elements to ints; if all you care about is whether they're even, you can do that as `lambda numstr: numstr[-1] in '02468'``.

Comment: @PaneerPushpam Can you argue why your way is better? o.0 And what's wrong with learning new things?

Comment: Could you clarify what your way is? I can't go by your code sample because it solves a completely different problem.

Comment: @abarnert, I left `map()` in there to handle `str`, `int`, or even `float` elements.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Well, I'm not sure the obvious extension of this problem to float is to sort based on whether the truncated integer is even or odd. The best extension I can think of is either all floats are even, or something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/92470). Or, more simply, just raise an exception because the question doesn't make sense…

Comment: this is clearly a homework assignment .... perhaps to show horribly inefficient sorting (perhaps an algorithms class, I can only pray this is not a CS class) .... OP shredded this question earlier ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064191/python-3-adding-two-numbers-and-converting-them-to-a-string

Answer (score 0):

There is a type of sort called [odd-even sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd%E2%80%93even_sort). But it has nothing to do with what you want.

Odd-even sort sorts your values, just like any other sort. The name comes from the fact that it's implemented by comparing odd-even indices and then even-odd indices (which makes it easier to parallelize than bubble sort; otherwise they're pretty much equivalent).

If you actually read the Wikipedia article you got the pseudocode from (or read the code you implemented), it makes this all very clear.

So, if you're asking how to fix your odd-even sort to partition an array into odd and even values… well, you can't. It's like asking how to "fix" your car's wheels so they can propel it through the air. Wheels can't propel a car through the air, at least not without such massive changes to their basic workings that they'd no longer have anything to do with what you started with. In the same way, a sorting algorithm can't partition your list into odd and even values without such massive changes to its basic workings that it would no longer have anything to do with what you started with.

---

You can, of course, build partitioning on top of sorting. For example:

```
def partition_odd_even(values, sort_function):
    decorated = [(value % 2, value) for value in values]
    sorted = sort_function(decorated)
    undecorated = [vv[1] for vv in decorated]
    return undecorated
```

Then, you can call this with any sorting function that works—a quicksort implementation, or the builtin `sorted` function, or anything else. You don't have to implement a whole different sort algorithm just because it has a confusingly similar name.

Plus, even if you want to do it that way, it's better to just use a `key` function, as in [TigerhawkT3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065014/908494).